# MediaTek Inc. MT7612U 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter slow on Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, mediatek

Update:
When it's get slow and the usb stop working, if I try to reboot i get this message:

```
mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: vendor request req:07 off:0430 failed:-71
```

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-29-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 6 × AMD Ryzen 5 3500X 6-Core Processor
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 560 Series

```
>> sudo dmesg | grep mt76

[   13.991544] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: ASIC revision: 76120044
[   14.187531] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: ROM patch build: 20141115060606a
[   14.432237] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.0.00
[   14.432242] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: Build: 1
[   14.432244] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: Build Time: 201507311614____
[   15.729352] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt76x2u
[   15.784584] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0 wlx0013ef8f123e: renamed from wlan0
[   63.773161] Workqueue: mt76 mt76u_tx_status_data [mt76_usb]
[   63.773366]  mt76x02_send_tx_status+0x25f/0x480 [mt76x02_lib]
[   63.773377]  mt76x02_tx_status_data+0x52/0x80 [mt76x02_lib]
[   63.773386]  mt76u_tx_status_data+0x67/0xd0 [mt76_usb]
[  299.700710] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: MAC error detected
[  300.028658] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: MAC error detected
[  300.140629] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: timed out waiting for pending tx
[  353.066515] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76120044
[  353.138936] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: ROM patch build: 20141115060606a
[  353.304685] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.0.00
[  353.304689] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: Build: 1
[  353.304690] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: Build Time: 201507311614____
[  354.332978] mt76x2u 3-4:1.0 wlx0013ef8f123e: renamed from wlan0

>> sudo dmesg | grep 80211

[27596.696402] ieee80211 phy3: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[27598.696295] ieee80211 phy4: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[28037.256384] ieee80211 phy5: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[28039.262674] ieee80211 phy6: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[54462.015374] ieee80211 phy7: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
```

I got an wifi adapter from mediatek. The MT7612U are built in kernel and thus should not have any issues, but the internet speed is way slower than should be. Eventually the speed get's normal but often it's get really slow.
Those times, if I try to check the lsusb it's hangs forever and if I reboot it's keeping looping in a message about vendor issues (I forgot how I can check this message in command line, since I am forced to do a hard reset when this happens)

```
>> sudo dmesg -w

https://pastebin.com/p9G6xuAx
```

Any suggestion in how I can debug it?

TY

Comment: Can you edit the question to include results from terminal for `sudo dmesg | grep mt76`

Comment: Anything for `sudo dmesg | grep 80211`

Comment: You might want to run `sudo dmesg -w` and see what happens when it slows down, it looks like it is disconnecting and reconnecting to the USB bus

Comment: It's seems the main issue it's related to the usb.
What's happens it's that after some time the usb kind of stop working. It's don't really stop (i can still use everything that it's connected to it) bit I can't use lsusb and on rebooting I get the error:

mt76x2u 3-4:1.0: vendor request req:07 off:0430 failed:-71

Comment: Looks like the fix is at https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/patch/8d0116580f2c5eafaea29acb2cbbc348ff853f5b.1667920478.git.lorenzo@kernel.org/

Comment: How I use that patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the patch to kernel source code after installing 22.10.  My similar wifi adapter doesn't seem to have the same issue and adding the patch didn't cause issues, so in terminal do

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/5.19.0-29-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko /lib/modules/5.19.0-29-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko.bak
cd /lib/modules/5.19.0-29-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/
sudo wget https://gitlab.com/jeremy.bomkamp/mac80211/-/raw/main/mac80211.ko
```

Reboot and see if it fixes it

Comment: it's still slow, but I will try this next:

https://github.com/morrownr/7612u/issues/17

I didn't had the usb issue yet, thought. So it's just unstable (and can be something from my internet itself)

Thus, I will close and pick this as the answer

Comment: I wouldn't accept an answer that doesn't fix the problem, you may need to file a bug report with Ubuntu